# In The Mandalorian S2 E14 “The Tragedy”, how did Boba Fett’s armor and the Beskar Spear survive

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the said episode, a turbo laser strike comes down from Moff Gideon's ship, a Arquitens-class command cruiser, and destroys the Razor Crest. However, in “The Gunslinger” (S1 E5)…

> THE MANDALORIAN: Sniper bolt. Only an MK-modified rifle could make that shot.
>
> TORO CALICAN: Are you all right?
>
> THE MANDALORIAN: Yeah. Hit me in the beskar, and at that range beskar held up.

…this implies that the Beskar could have been punched through at a closer range. Since turbolasers are much more powerful than blaster rifles, wouldn’t it have at least damaged the spear and armor or left it extremely hot, if not destroyed it?

Comment: Plot armor appears as needed.

Comment: Just realized that it wouldn’t even look like beskar spear and armor, just a bunch of beskar blobs from it melting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, you are comparing apples to oranges. Sniper bolts are designed to be precise, focusing their energy in a small, concentrated area. Turbolasers, while they hold a much larger amount of energy, have a much larger impact area, more evenly distributing it, thus decreasing the energy per unit mass absorbed by the beskar. For another, the turbolasers hit the ship, not the armor or spear. The explosion from the ship would have been even less concentrated, so it would have given less energy per unit mass, allowing the beskar, which has a ridiculously high melting point (and, seemingly, also an incredibly high specific heat, though that seems to be contradicted by its apparent rapid cooling time), to survive unharmed. Also, as it had time to cool off, "extremely hot" would not have particularly mattered in the context of the plot. Disney may have considered this, or, as Dosco Jones suggested, it could have just been very convenient plot armor with no premeditation, but this is my scientific explanation.